# Unable to Grant Access for File Upload with WKWebView's Full-Screen Mode

Tags: swift, macos

I'm currently working with a macOS application that incorporates a WKWebView. My goal is to allow users to upload files through the WKWebView by entering full-screen mode. However, despite my attempts, I haven't been able to grant access for file uploads within this context.

Here's the code snippet I'm using to enter full-screen mode and enable the WKWebView's layer:

```
    let presentationOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [
        .autoHideDock,
        .autoHideToolbar,
        .disableHideApplication,
        .disableForceQuit,
        .fullScreen,
    ]


webView.enterFullScreenMode(screen, withOptions: [
    NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeAllScreens: presentationOptions.rawValue
])
webView.wantsLayer = true
```